# Calculate total price on different percentage for each increment

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to write a calculator for price estimation

so that :

for 1000 MTU price will be 0.035 so total will become 35
for 2000 MTU price will be 0.034 total will become 67
for 3000 MTU price will be .0329 total will become 98.79

and so on....

I write the following code but its giving NaN error.

Any new suggestion to write a efficient code will be appreciated.

```
<p id= "rangeValue" >

</p>
<div class="range-wrap">
        <div class="range-value" id="rangeV"></div>
<input id="myinput" type="range" name="points" min="1000" max="100000" value="1000" oninput="rangeValue.innerText = this.value" >
</div>
```

```
const slider = document.getElementById("myinput")
const min = slider.min
const max = slider.max
const value = slider.value

slider.style.background = `linear-gradient(to right, #0080FF 0%, #0080FF ${(value-min)/(max-min)*100}%, #596680 ${(value-min)/(max-min)*100}%, #596680 100%)`

slider.oninput = function() {
  this.style.background = `linear-gradient(to right, #0080FF 0%, #0080FF ${(this.value-this.min)/(this.max-this.min)*100}%, #596680 ${(this.value-this.min)/(this.max-this.min)*100}%, #596680 100%)`
};


// Add a change event listener to the range slider
   slider.addEventListener('change', function() {
  // Get the value of the range slider
  var value = this.value;
  var container = document.querySelector('#rangeValue');
  
  let cost;
  function calculateCost(value) {
  if (value === 1000) {
    cost = 0.0350;
  } else if (value === 2000) {
    cost = 0.0340;
  } else {
    cost = 0;
  }
  return cost;
}
var totval=value * cost;
totval = totval.toFixed(2);
  
  container.innerHTML = totval;
  // Print the value to the console
 // console.log(value);
});

const
    range = document.getElementById('myinput'),
    rangeV = document.getElementById('rangeV'),
    setValue = ()=>{
        const
            newValue = Number( (range.value - range.min) * 100 / (range.max - range.min) ),
            newPosition = 10 - (newValue * 0.2);
        rangeV.innerHTML = `<span>${range.value}</span>`;
        rangeV.style.left = `calc(${newValue}% + (${newPosition}px))`;
    };
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", setValue);
range.addEventListener('input', setValue);
```

````
#myinput {
  border-radius: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb {

  -webkit-appearance: none;
   width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
   background: #0080FF;
}


.range-wrap{
    width: 500px;
    position: relative;
}
.range-value{
    position: absolute;
    top: 150%;
}
.range-value span{
    width: 30px;
    height: 24px;
    line-height: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    background: transparent;
    color: #0A0E1C;
    font-size: 20px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    border-radius: 6px;
}
.range-value span:before{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    margin-top: -1px;
}```
````

Comment: If its a javascript error, I would recommend stripping out all of the code that does't produce that. So the CSS etc, and just add the minimal reproducible code. Also a quick glance shows you don't actually use calculateCost. anywhere

Comment: `element.value` would return a string, so you'd need to convert it to a number.

Comment: I am trying to get the following [result](http://mixpanel.com/pricing/plan-builder/) with mine value

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I suspect that the logic is too rigid. The `value` will only be 1000 or 2000 in 2 specific points in the Range. Do you mean that if value is Greater than 1000 and less than 2000 it should be a specific cost? What about if it is greater than 2000?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `parseInt()` to convert `input value` from `string` to `integer`, so you can calculate your prices.
Other than that You are using a function `calculateCost()` inside your event listener, I correct this in the code, so this is the result:

```js
const slider = document.getElementById("myinput")
const min = parseInt(slider.min)
const max = parseInt(slider.max)
const value = parseInt(slider.value)

slider.style.background = `linear-gradient(to right, #0080FF 0%, #0080FF ${(value-min)/(max-min)*100}%, #596680 ${(value-min)/(max-min)*100}%, #596680 100%)`

slider.oninput = function() {
  this.style.background = `linear-gradient(to right, #0080FF 0%, #0080FF ${(this.value-this.min)/(this.max-this.min)*100}%, #596680 ${(this.value-this.min)/(this.max-this.min)*100}%, #596680 100%)`
};


// Add a change event listener to the range slider
slider.addEventListener('change', function() {
  // Get the value of the range slider
  var value = parseInt(this.value);
  var container = document.querySelector('#rangeValue');

  let cost;
    if (value === 1000) {
      cost = 0.0350;
    } else if (value === 2000) {
      cost = 0.0340;
    } else {
      cost = 0;
    }
  var totval=value * cost;
  totval = totval.toFixed(2);

  container.innerHTML = totval;
  // Print the value to the console
  // console.log(value);
});

const
    range = document.getElementById('myinput'),
    rangeV = document.getElementById('rangeV'),
    setValue = ()=>{
        const
            newValue = Number( (range.value - range.min) * 100 / (range.max - range.min) ),
            newPosition = 10 - (newValue * 0.2);
        rangeV.innerHTML = `<span>${range.value}</span>`;
        rangeV.style.left = `calc(${newValue}% + (${newPosition}px))`;
    };
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", setValue);
range.addEventListener('input', setValue);
```

```css
#myinput {
  border-radius: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb {

  -webkit-appearance: none;
   width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
   background: #0080FF;
}


.range-wrap{
    width: 500px;
    position: relative;
}
.range-value{
    position: absolute;
    top: 150%;
}
.range-value span{
    width: 30px;
    height: 24px;
    line-height: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    background: transparent;
    color: #0A0E1C;
    font-size: 20px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    border-radius: 6px;
}
.range-value span:before{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    margin-top: -1px;
}
```

```html
<p id= "rangeValue" >
</p>
<div class="range-wrap">
<div class="range-value" id="rangeV"></div>
<input id="myinput" type="range" name="points" min="1000" max="100000" value="1000" oninput="rangeValue.innerText = this.value" >
</div>
```